# Adding Beautifulsoup to Zenrows

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am super new to coding and so far, I am just copying solutions I found online.
I encountered a challenge when scraping this site.
https://www.oneroof.co.nz/property/auckland/bucklands-beach/18-camwell-close/H3rQw

I would like to get Oneroof estimate (class="text-xl md:hidden text-secondary font-bold").
I believe this site is protected to anti web scraping. So I found Zenrows to bypass.

I successfully retrieved the html but I don't know how to return the result I want.

Tried to combine Zenrows with Beautifulsoup but not sure if that's a proper approach.

```
# pip install zenrows
from zenrows import ZenRowsClient

client = ZenRowsClient("daf1d79772a751a7d680055ed81a0d5b47cb2bb6")
url = "https://www.oneroof.co.nz/property/auckland/bucklands-beach/18-camwell-close/H3rQw"
params = {"js_render":"true","json_response":"true","js_instructions":"%5B%7B%22click%22%3A%22.selector%22%7D%2C%7B%22wait%22%3A500%7D%2C%7B%22fill%22%3A%5B%22.input%22%2C%22value%22%5D%7D%2C%7B%22wait_for%22%3A%22.slow_selector%22%7D%5D"}

response = client.get(url, params=params)

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
mydivs = str(soup.find(class_="text-xl md:hidden text-secondary font-bold"))
print(mydivs)
```

But this returned "None"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the BeautifulSoup response to HTML DOM to apply xpath and get the desired values.
find the code snippet below for the same.

```py
# pip install zenrows
from zenrows import ZenRowsClient

client = ZenRowsClient("daf1d79772a751a7d680055ed81a0d5b47cb2bb6")
url = "https://www.oneroof.co.nz/property/auckland/bucklands-beach/18-camwell-close/H3rQw"
params = {"js_render":"true","json_response":"true","js_instructions":"%5B%7B%22click%22%3A%22.selector%22%7D%2C%7B%22wait%22%3A500%7D%2C%7B%22fill%22%3A%5B%22.input%22%2C%22value%22%5D%7D%2C%7B%22wait_for%22%3A%22.slow_selector%22%7D%5D"}

response = client.get(url, params=params)

import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
# converting BeautifulSoup response to HTML DOM
dom = etree.HTML(str(bs))

# To get complete value ($1,750,000) use xpath1 and xpath2 for short number ($1.75M)
# xpath1 = "//span[contains(text(),'OneRoof estimate')]/following-sibling::span[1]"
xpath2 = "//span[contains(text(),'OneRoof estimate')]/following-sibling::span[2]"
nodes = dom.xpath(xpath2)
estimation = nodes[0].text.strip()
print(estimation)
```

**Output:** **$1.75M**